# Returning a function from a Module

Tags: differential-equations

I'm having problems working with the output from `DSolve` whilst in a module. To handle the result outside a module typically I would do something like

```
 f[t] = y[t] /. solution
```

But inside a module my `t` is now `t$` followed by some numbers. How can I create and return a function from the output of `DSolve` inside a module?

---

Here is my code:

```
Module[{equations,solution,h,t},
  m=1;
  g=9.8;
  equations = {y''[t]== -m g,y'[0]==100,y[0]==0};
  solution = Flatten@ DSolve[equations,y,t];
  h[t] = y[t] /. solution;
  h[1]]
```

I get `h = 100. t$16608-4.9 t$16608^2`, but `h[1] = h$16909[1)`.

Comment: OK, it is not clear what you try to achieve. There is an architectural error if you try to return an lokal variable like `h`. Furthermore, (in your additional post) you don't return a *function*! You return only an expression. Can you please clear up what exactly you try and how you want to use it? Btw, you can **edit** your question and improve it. Don't write an additional post.

Comment: I think the most straightforward answer is just "use `Block` rather than `Module` in this case", so I voted to close this as a duplicate of a question the explains the distinctions rather well.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html  You're using `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`); and you should use a pattern `h[t_]`.  You could also simply skip `h` and return `y[1] /. solution`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `DSolve[eqs, y, t]` instead of `DSolve[eqs, y[t], t]` to get a rule like `y -> Function[ arg, ... ]`, so the `t`, whether it's local or not, will not make difference.

```
Module[{t}, DSolve[y'[t] == t, y, t] ]
```

> ```
> {{y -> Function[{t$31879}, t$31879^2/2 + C[1]]}}
> ```

```
y[t] /. %
```

> ```
> {t^2/2 + C[1]}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You could return a pure function.  Like this

```
m = 1;
g = 9.8;

h = Module[{equations, solution, t},
      equations = {y''[t] == -m g, y'[0] == 100, y[0] == 0};
      solution = First@Flatten@DSolve[equations, y[t], t];
      With[{x = Last @solution /. t -> #1}, x &]]
```

> ```
> 100. #1 - 4.9 #1^2 &
> ```

```
 h[1]
```

> 95.1